# not able to execute block module in ansible yml script

Tags: linux, ansible

I am using block module in below ansible playbook. Basically if `files` exist then only I want to execute Play 2 and Play3 but for some reason I get an error when I execute below playbook.

```
---
- name: Play 1
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: find the latest file
    find: paths=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/files
          file_type=file
          age=-1m
          age_stamp=mtime
    register: files

  - name: Play 2 & 3 if Play 1 has a file
    block:
      - name: Play 2
        hosts: all
        serial: 5
        tasks:
          - name: copy latest file
            copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data01/admin/files/goldy.init.qa

          - name: copy latest file
            copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data02/admin/files/goldy.init.qa

      - name: Play 3
        hosts: 127.0.0.1
        tasks:
          - name: execute command
            shell: ./data_init --init_file ./goldy.init.qa
    when: files != ""
```

Below is the error. Any idea what is wrong I am doing here?

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/test.yml': line 14, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    block:
      - name: Play 2
        ^ here
```

Comment: Plays can't be nested.

Comment: I see so how can I fix it? Basically I want to execute Play2 and Play3 only if there is files present in Play1. Is this possible to do in ansible?

Comment: Sure. Just start Play2 (or 3) and use the variables declared in Play1. (If this is what you want). Why is it necessary to start another play?

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you provide an example? Basically if there are no files present in Play1 module then I dont even want to execute Play2 or Play3 so I tried using `end_play` but it skips all tasks in Play1.

Comment: You're the one to make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Step by step.

Comment: what I have in my question is not mcve? I think it has all the steps detailed and also mentioned why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here stems from the mismatch of [Play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example) and [Block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html). Ansible playbooks may contain one or many Plays, a Play is a top order structure in a Playbook (remember Playbooks are just YAML so it's all effectively a data structure). Blocks come in when you want to combine a serious of tasks as efficiently an unit that you can take group action on such as conditionals, but also for error catching and recovery. Blocks are part of a Play, they can be put almost anywhere a task can. However in the syntax you've defined new Plays nested within others which is not allowed. Hope this helps, happy automating!

Comment: got it now. so how can I do what I want to do? Basically if files doesnt exist in Play1 then I don't want to execute Play2 and Play3 at all. Is this possible to do?

Comment: What you might consider doing is either breaking out what you want to do into [Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) such that that series of tasks can easily be re-used and then use [Includes and Imports](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html) to import then where you want. Or simple have a task file that you import/include.

Answer (score 0):

there are several things wrong in this and I assume you're new to ansible. You cannot put a name on a block.  your structure is also wrong.  files is not defined.  try:

```
---
- name: Play 1
  hosts: 127.0.0.1



  tasks:
  - name: find the latest file
    find: paths=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/files
          file_type=file
          age=-1m
          age_stamp=mtime
    register: files
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ files }}"
    when: files != ""

  - block:
    - name: copy latest file
      copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data01/admin/files/goldy.init.qa

    - name: copy latest file
      copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data02/admin/files/goldy.init.qa

    - name: execute command
      shell: ./data_init --init_file ./goldy.init.qa
    when: files != ""
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in your ansible script compared to mine. It is same I think.

Comment: apologies, I pasted your script. I edited it, please test.

Comment: Hi flash, try using this script.  It should work if your system is properly configured.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. `Play1` I am running on my localhost box but `Play2` is being run on remote servers and then `Play3` again on my localhost box so I dont think I can combine everything in one Play.

Comment: Ok now I understand.  Try using delegate_to

Comment: can you provide an example basis on my solution?

Comment: are you still around?

Comment: I suggest you read about inventories first.  I assumed you are running all the tasks to the local system because you have hosts defined as localhost. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html  test with "ansible hostname -m setup"  add option --ask-pass if you want to test login.